# AngularJS Service to create BootStrap 3.0 Popup same as JQuery Mobile Popup

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, dialog, popup

I would like a BootStrap 3.0, AngularJS service that provides similar functionality as JQuery Mobile's Popup.

I suppose what I am looking for is a Modeless dialog.

The Popup should allow me to place a form as content and ideally support transitions in/out.

I would like it to support triggers on pre-open, opened, pre-closed and closed events.

A usecase that I would love to be able to support is to be able to drag a field value from an active Popup down to an existing field on the parent element then closing on the drop event.

Ideally I would like it to be as simple as the $Modal service (leverage it if possible) in which I can pass in the content and some configuration parameters.

I should be able to click out to close, or enforce a Modal like behaviour.

Like $modal, there will only ever be a single popup active.

Just like in JQM,  I would need to support positioning of the popup anywhere within the page.

Can I get this all from just the bootstrap-ui $Modal service or some of this functionality? If so can you show me how.

Comment: take a look at http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: I have looked at angular-ui bootstrap, that's what I am referring to with $Modal service.

Comment: ok, you need to be a bit more clear on your question then. The link I posted is an angular service (directive) that can make a modal dialog

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, but I am looking for a modeless dialog ... I thought I was pretty clear on that.